# Inconsistency in SpriteKit API SKWarpGeometryGrid

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

```
let sourcePositions: [vector_float2] = [
    vector_float2(0, 1),   vector_float2(0.5, 1),   vector_float2(1, 1),   
    vector_float2(0, 0.5), vector_float2(0.5, 0.5), vector_float2(1, 0.5),  
    vector_float2(0, 0),   vector_float2(0.5, 0),   vector_float2(1, 0)]
```

Apple API Reference

> The origin of the vertex positions is in the bottom left: The following code shows how you can create an array of evenly spaced vertices which could act as a default set of source positions for a warp geometry with two columns and two rows. The first item in the array refers to the position at the bottom left and the last item refers to the position at the top right.

Coordinates 0,1 being bottom left, however if we look at say anchorPoint of SKNode 0,0 would be bottom left with 0,1 being top left.

Is there something I'm missing? Is it irrelevant what coordinates are assigned to each position as that's determined by the row and column properties

Comment: It looks like the documentation is incorrect

Comment: You can [file bugs](http://bugreport.apple.com) against Apple's developer docs, too, not just against the softwar/SDK.